# Updating Backbonejs model from another Requirejs Module

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I created a Backbonejs model in a RequireJs module that way :

```
define(['model/newmodel']), function (Newmodel) {
    var newmodel = new Newmodel();
}
```

I create a new module where I'd like to update my newmodel

```
define(['views/view']), function (View) {
    // I'd like to modify some properties of the 'newmodel' object here
}
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: How do you want to update it? This is very odd, you normally wouldn't use a module to update an instance.

Comment: What are the names of the files containing these two define calls? Remember that the module you define is based on these file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Sulc's approach is certainly one way to go, but you absolutely can pass instance around in Require if you have a good reason to.  In general it makes more sense to pass around classes, but if you have a "global-ish" object it might make sense to pass it directly.

First off I'd start by getting your capitalization consistent: it's pretty universal practice to name classes with capital letters, and instances with lower-case ones, which would make you rename your "newmodel" file/module to "Newmodel:

```
define(['model/Newmodel']), function (Newmodel) {
    var newmodel = new Newmodel();
}
```

With that out of the way you can make your "newmodel" (lower-case) file/module return the instance itself:

define(['model/Newmodel']), function (Newmodel) {
    var newmodel = new Newmodel();
    return newmodel;
}

Once you've done that your view can do whatever it wants to that instance by bringing it in normally through require:

```
define(['model/newmodel', 'views/view']), function (newmodel, View) {
    // I'd like to modify some properties of the 'newmodel' object here
    modifyPropertiesOf(newmodel)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do this instead:

```
define(['model/newmodel', 'views/view']), function (NewModel, View) {
    var newmodel = new Newmodel();
    var myView = new View({
        model: newmodel
    });
}
```

You usually use requireJS to make sure "classes" are loaded when your code needs them, not to pass around instances.